# How to reverse the direction of an animation in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm having a hard time understanding how HTML5 animation works. I need some enlightenment.

What I want to do is make the rectangle animate to the bottom of the canvas then, come back up to the top of the canvas. It seems the problem is I am not setting the rectangle's y location properly. I noticed when I set the rectangle's speed different from the current speed it reacts the way I want it to. The rectangle wants to go back up, but it is remembering that it is suppose to go down. So it is stuck trying to decide what to do.

How do I initially set the rectangle's y location, and do I need to update it constantly?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>canvas animation</title>
<style>
#animated {
    border: 1px solid black;  
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>canvas animation</h1>

<canvas id="animated" width="500" height="300"></canvas>

<script>
        var xLoc = 0;
        var yLoc = 0;
        var speed = 5;

        window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
            return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
            function(callback) {
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
            };
         })();

        function animateDown() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("animated");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);           

            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(xLoc, yLoc, 300, 150); // yLoc-canvas.height = -300
            context.fillStyle = "rgb(247, 209, 23)";
            context.fill();

            yLoc += 4;

            if (yLoc > canvas.height - 150) {
                yLoc -= speed;
            } else if (yLoc < 0) {
                yLoc += speed;
            }

            requestAnimFrame(function() {
                animateDown();
            });
         }

        window.onload = function() {
            animateDown();
        };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not telling it to reverse. You are telling it to back off, and it gets caught in a never-ending cycle.

Alter your code, to have a variable `direction` to tell it where to go (up/down):

```
<script>
        var xLoc = 0;
        var yLoc = 0;
        var speed = 5;
        var direction = 1;   // Defaults to 'down'

        window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
            return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
            function(callback) {
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
            };
         })();

        function animateDown() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("animated");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);           

            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(xLoc, yLoc, 300, 150); // yLoc-canvas.height = -300
            context.fillStyle = "rgb(247, 209, 23)";
            context.fill();

            yLoc += speed * direction;   // Increase by speed in the given direction

            if (yLoc > canvas.height - 150) {
                direction = -1;  // Move up again (decrease)
            } else if (yLoc < 0) {
                direction = 1;   // Move downwards
            }

            requestAnimFrame(function() {
                animateDown();
            });
         }

        window.onload = function() {
            animateDown();
        };
</script>
```

Comment: Eric, why can I not use yLoc --; to reverse the direction? I'm trying to understand why I have to create a new variable in order to control yLoc's direction vs. using yLoc's own properties to reverse itself.

Comment: I got it now. I have to set the yLoc's motion increment first in order for the logic statement to capture yLoc's positioning to execute the logic statement.

Comment: The reason is because yLoc first being decremented so it is less than `canvas.height - 150`. Next time it gets called, it gets incremented above that threshold; which makes it decrement *again*. So basicly it gets stuck by incrementing / decrementing by `5` all the time.

Comment: May the force be with you, always.